# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/time/SUTimeMain

Tags: java, exception, jar

When I am running the following command:

```
java -Dpos.model=edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger -cp stanford-corenlp-2012-07-06.jar:stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.time.SUTimeMain -in.type TEXTFILE -date <YYYY-MM-dd> -i <input.txt> -o <output file>
```

I am getting following error:

```
    entException in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/time/SUTimeMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.time.SUTimeMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: edu.stanford.nlp.time.SUTimeMain. Program will exit.
```

But when I run this command:

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt
```

I do not get any error.

My stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar file contains both edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP as well as edu/stanford/nlp/time/SUTimeMain.

Then why one command runs and other don't.
Thanks in advance

Comment: did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing different JAR files in your commands.

```
java
-Dpos.model=edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger
-cp stanford-corenlp-2012-07-06.jar:stanford-corenlp-2012-07-09models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar
-Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.time.SUTimeMain
-in.type TEXTFILE
-date <YYYY-MM-dd>
-i <input.txt>
-o <output file>
```

versus

```
java
-cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar:xom.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar
-Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
-annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref
-file input.txt
```

The first uses `stanford-corenlp-2012-07-06.jar` and the second uses `stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar`

You say that `stanford-corenlp-2012-07-06.jar` contains the missing class.  That explains why that one works and the previous one does not.

Also, there are several differences between these commands.  When asking for help with a "this works and this doesn't" scenario, it is a good idea to limit the differences to the single parameter that makes a difference.  This would accomplish 3 things:

1. Show the community that you have tried.
2. Prevent members from spending time troubleshooting a component that is not related to the problem.
3. It may cause you to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Not sure how I messed that up.